# Tomcat 8 Session Replication with Redis

Tags: redis, load-balancing, tomcat8

Can session replication be implemented on Tomcat 8 with redis? I am not able to find redis session manager jar for tomcat 8!

Answer (score 6):

There is a ready solution offered by [Redisson](https://redisson.org) framework - Redis based In-Memory Data Grid.

Two steps how to use it:

1. Add RedissonSessionManager into context.xml

   ```
    <Manager className="org.redisson.tomcat.RedissonSessionManager"
         configPath="${catalina.base}/redisson.yaml" />
   ```

`configPath` - path to Redisson JSON or YAML config. See [configuration wiki page](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration) for more details.

2. Copy both jars into TOMCAT_BASE/lib directory: `redisson-all-3.x.x.jar` and `redisson-tomcat-9-3.x.x.jar`

Boost Tomcat Session Manager performance up to **4x times** with [Redisson PRO](https://redisson.pro) version.